# Tensorflow on Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: raspberrypi, tensorflow

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a Raspberry Pi.
Both my Ubuntu and Python3 installations are 64-bit.
I'm now trying to install Tensorflow so that I can run (not train) a model.

I've tried various blog-posts, installed all the dependencies, etc. However, I am always faced with the same error:

```
> pip3 install tensorflow
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

and running `pip install --upgrade tensorflow` gives the same error.

What is wrong? How can I install tensorflow on my Raspberry Pi?